# Git unexpectedly ignoring files excluded in .gitignore

Tags: git

My .gitignore file contains the following lines:

```
make/
!make/*.mak
```

When I run "git add make/file.mak" I get the following error:

```
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
make
Use -f if you really want to add them.
fatal: no files added
```

Why am I getting this error when I added make/file.mak to the exception list?

Answer (score 3):

Because `make/` itself has not been overridden. Change the first line to `/make/*`.

Comment: You mean `make/*` or I don't know what I'm talking about?

Comment: From `gitignore(5)`: "A leading slash matches the beginning of the pathname." `make/*` will match anywhere in the pathname, while `/make/*` will only match from the repo root.

Comment: I tried that solution (/make/ and !/make/*.mak) and it didn't solve the problem. Also, note that I only want to exclude *.mak, not *.

Comment: @balor123: did you get an answer? solve this by yourself? I'm having the exact same problem...